Why MediaFoundation can not capture dxgi buffer data on some machine?
I'm use MediaFoundation capture video from my camera,and for good performance, I try to set hardward acceleration by IMFMediaSourceEx::SetD3DManager() function，and I also create IMFDXGIDeviceManager and set it, Here is the related code:
    if (CreateDXGIManager()) {
        IMFMediaSourceEx* source_ext = nullptr;
        HRESULT hr = mediaSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&source_ext));
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = source_ext->SetD3DManager(mf_dxgi_device_manager_.Get());
            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                LogWarrning("%s: failed to set d3d manager, errorcode = %x", __FUNCTION__, hr);
            }
            else {
                LogMessage("%s: set d3d manager success", __FUNCTION__);
            }
            source_ext->Release();
        }
        else {
            LogWarrning("%s: get IMFMediaSourceEx failed, errorcode = %x", __FUNCTION__, hr);
        }
    }
bool ButelVideoCaptureAsyn::CreateDXGIManager()
{
    LogMessage("%s", __FUNCTION__);
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&d3d_device_reset_token_,
        &mf_dxgi_device_manager_);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        LogError("%s create dxgi device manager failed", __FUNCTION__);
        return false;
    }

    hr = mf_dxgi_device_manager_->ResetDevice(butel_context_->D3D11Device(),
        d3d_device_reset_token_);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        LogError("%s dxgi device manager reset device failed", __FUNCTION__);
        return false;
    }
    LogMessage("%s success", __FUNCTION__);
    return true;
}

In some machine, my program works well, I can capture dxgi memory data, and use video processor to render texture directly.But in some machine,it can't work,especially, I tested my program on two machines with the same graphics card. The program executed without error, but the dxgi buffer data was captured on one machine and not on the other. I can't understand the reason for this result. If you have any good ideas to help me solve this problem, I would be very grateful.
next is the graphic card information of the machine
enter image description here
I hope someone can help me solve this problem.
